# How to automatically cut text to fit fixed block size?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have block with width in % and height in *rem* and I need to fill it with random-length text. I need the number of visible lines (block has overflow:hidden) to be integer and the last line to end with "...read full text" link. Of course, this must work for every font/line size and any page scale.

How to realize this?

https://jsfiddle.net/2go48yum/

```
<div class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tenetur distinctio tempore porro voluptatum iste, pariatur. Nam ea alias aliquam nesciunt, tenetur autem nisi laborum officiis voluptatibus laudantium esse, ut reiciendis? ipsum dolor sit amet,
  consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum quisquam, natus in similique consequatur officia aperiam vel voluptatibus, beatae possimus. Vero ab rerum ratione doloremque veritatis totam quas facere porro. ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Delectus
  est dolorem laborum eius quia architecto, adipisci tempora blanditiis, nisi aliquid expedita numquam debitis. Commodi perspiciatis, inventore accusantium animi quas</div>


.content {
  width: 50%;
  height: 15rem;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: This is not possible with plain CSS. Look into https://github.com/ShinyChang/react-text-truncate on how they did that. You could however cut the text after a certain character length with JS and `String#substr`.

Comment: With dynamic text-size and scale fixed text-length is useless.

Answer (score 1):

```css
p { margin: 0; padding: 0; font-family: sans-serif;}

.ellipsis {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 200px;
 line-height: 25px;
 margin: 20px;
 border: 1px solid #AAA;
  }

.ellipsis:before {
 content:"";
 float: left;
 width: 5px; height: 200px; }

.ellipsis > *:first-child {
 float: right;
 width: 100%;
 margin-left: -5px; }  

.ellipsis:after {
 content: "\02026";  
 box-sizing: content-box;
 -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
 float: right; position: relative;
 top: -25px; left: 100%; 
 width: 3em; margin-left: -3em;
 padding-right: 5px;
 text-align: right;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="ellipsis"><div>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tenetur distinctio tempore porro voluptatum iste, pariatur. Nam ea alias aliquam nesciunt, tenetur autem nisi laborum officiis voluptatibus laudantium esse, ut reiciendis? ipsum dolor sit amet,
  consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum quisquam, natus in similique consequatur officia aperiam vel voluptatibus, beatae possimus. Vero ab rerum ratione doloremque veritatis totam quas facere porro. ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Delectus
  est dolorem laborum eius quia architecto, adipisci tempora blanditiis, nisi aliquid expedita numquam debitis. Commodi perspiciatis, inventore accusantium animi quas</p>  
</div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**For infos and not reliable**.

*With **CSS** you could* try using `mix-blend-mode` and `position:sticky`. But most of the browser will not play it *(At this time, FF&Chrome understand both mix-blend-mode and sticky )*.

```css
.content {
  float: left;
  border: solid;
  margin: 1%;
  width: 45%;
  height: 11rem;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: yellow;
  text-align: justify;
  /*text-align-last:justify;for test purpose only */
}

.content:after {
  position: sticky;
  bottom: 0;
  float: right;
  margin-left: -1em;
  width: 1em;
  content: '...';
  display: inline-block;
  background: inherit;
  mix-blend-mode: screen;
  z-index: 1;
}

.disclaimer {
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tenetur distinctio tempore porro voluptatum iste, pariatur. Nam ea alias aliquam nesciunt, tenetur autem nisi laborum officiis voluptatibus laudantium esse, ut reiciendis? ipsum dolor sit amet,
  consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum quisquam, natus in similique consequatur officia aperiam vel voluptatibus, beatae possimus. Vero ab rerum ratione doloremque veritatis totam quas facere porro. ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Delectus
  est dolorem laborum eius quia architecto, adipisci tempora blanditiis, nisi aliquid expedita numquam debitis. Commodi perspiciatis, inventore accusantium animi quas</div>
<div class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tenetur distinctio tempore porro voluptatum iste, pariatur. Nam ea alias aliquam nesciunt, tenetur autem nisi laborum officiis voluptatibus laudantium esse, ut reiciendis? <br/> 
<b class="disclaimer">If you see this text, mix-blend-mode is not supported</b></div>
```